# 'Scavenger' reading dead alien's mind. Turns out it's a small girl

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A short science fiction story I'm looking for: a 'scavenger' (or was he called 'vulture'?) is a policeman who reads the mind of the dying. He's a bit of a pariah. He's called to a crashed spaceship, where he reads the mind of the horribly burnt, small alien body. He sees weird trees against a weird sky. Finally he realises that it wasn't an alien but a child, and that what he saw was a child's drawing.
I read this story in a schoolbook for Dutch high school, when I was about 14 (I think), before 1990. The schoolbook also had bios of HG Wells and Heinlein. This sounds a bit like Fredric Brown type of story. I've been trying for decades to find the story back, but google has been no help! Anyone?

Comment: Accepting the answer (as you’ve done) is all that’s needed to indicate a question has been answered correctly. There’s no need to add it into the question itself

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that you probably remember a short story by James Blish.  I read it a paperback collection of James Blish stories titled *Galactic Cluster* (1959).

And from the list of stories in *Galactic Cluster* (1959) https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?14954 I think that it is "Tomb Tapper" (1956).

Here is a link to a list of some or all of the publications of "Tomb Tapper":

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55742

And you can set it to display all the covers of publications which include "Tomb Tapper" to see if any look familiar to you.

The protagonist is a member of the US Air National Guard who is a "tomb tapper" with a machine to read the thoughts of dead, dying, or unconscious crashed airplane pilots & passengers.  A Soviet aircraft has crashed during World War Three and he is brought in to read the mind of the Soviet pilot who is still trapped in the wreckage.

Here is a link to an online copy of *Best science Fiction Stories by James Blish* (1973) which should include "Tomb Tapper":  https://archive.org/details/bestscienceficti0000blis/page/n7/mode/1up

Comment: That's it! Been driving me nuts. I kept circling back to Laumer's *Doorstep*, but no pictures there. Well done.